# Как установить (интегрировать) DISM 10 на Windows 7, заменив «родной» DISM 6.1?

Tags: windows, cmd

Пишу скрипты интерпретатора команд (**CMD**) для создания "сборок" Windows путём выполнения команд **DISM** (интеграция обновлений, отключение компонентов, сжатие, экспорт и т.д.). Обслуживать автономные образы Windows (wim-файлы) можно версией DISM не ниже чем сам образ! Проблема в том, что на моём основном компьютере установлена Windows 7, а если мне нужно обработать образ Windows 8.1 или 10, то приходится на тестовом компьютере устанавливать нужную ОС, и собирать "сборку" на нём.

На Windows 7 можно установить, например, последний ADK для Windows 10 (1803), который содержит DISM 10. Но файл *dism.exe* новой версии не заменяет собой поставляемый с Windows 7, а размещается в папке установки "Windows Kits". При этом создаётся ярлык в меню Пуск для запуска командной оболочки с "особыми параметрами" откуда становятся доступными возможности DISM 10 путём "ручного" ввода команд. Естественно, автоматическое выполнение команд DISM 10 из скрипта недоступно, так как система в случае обнаружения команды dism в скрипте обращается к "родной" DISM 6.1.

Как сделать так, чтобы под Windows 7 можно было обслуживать автономные образы новых версий ОС?

Comment: Вписать путь к новому dism в начало path?

Comment: Так и сделал! Вначале обрадовался, что получилось. А затем обнаружил что кое-что не работает. Команда dism /Get-ProvisionedAppxPackages из скрипта не сработала - в логах ошибка: нет такой команды.